# jquery .trigger("load") doesn't always work in IE

Tags: jquery, image, triggers, load

I am trying to fade in a div with 13 images once the images are loaded. The code below works in chrome and FF but only runs the load function 11 times in IE therefore never fading in the div. The each function runs 13 times. Any ideas what's going wrong?

```
var loadCounter = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var nImages = $("#Content img").length;

  $("#Content img").one("load", function() {
      loadCounter++;
      if(nImages == loadCounter) {
         $("#Content").show("fade", 1000);
      }
  }).each(function() {
      if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
  });
});
```

The div:

```
<div id="Content" style="display:none;">
    <div id="front2-01_">
        <img id="front2_01" src="images/front2_01.png" width="848" height="225" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="front2-02_">
        <img id="front2_02" src="images/front2_02.png" width="697" height="22" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="blog_"><a href=""><img id="blog" src="images/blog.png" width="99" height="81" alt="" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="front2-04_">
        <img id="front2_04" src="images/front2_04.png" width="52" height="428" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="front2-05_">
        <img id="front2_05" src="images/front2_05.png" width="133" height="406" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="about_"><a href=""><img id="about" src="images/about.png" width="108" height="75" alt="" border="0"/></a>
    </div>
    <div id="front2-07_">
        <img id="front2_07" src="images/front2_07.png" width="456" height="30" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="front2-08_">
        <img id="front2_08" src="images/front2_08.png" width="134" height="376" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="comein_"><a href=""><img id="comein" src="images/comein.png" width="133" height="126" alt="" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="front2-10_">
        <img id="front2_10" src="images/front2_10.png" width="189" height="376" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="front2-11_">
        <img id="front2_11" src="images/front2_11.png" width="99" height="347" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="front2-12_">
        <img id="front2_12" src="images/front2_12.png" width="108" height="331" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="front2-13_">
        <img id="front2_13" src="images/front2_13.png" width="133" height="250" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $("#Content1 img").one("load" ?? `one` or `on`??

Comment: typo sorry it is #Content in the code

Comment: Same result unfortunately. Strange thing is this works for other pages with the same div name but a different number of images.

Comment: Can you provide your all code?

Comment: `one` is correct. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Comment: Thanks. one() or on() doesn't affect the result. I have added the html of the div for reference.

Comment: I just checked and the problem seems to only be there in IE 10, IE 11 worked as expected.